# TFS 2013 optional script is not being executed

Tags: tfsbuild

I wonder why I don't see any output of my prebuild.ps1 script.
It should print hello world `write-host "hello world"` and next do some xcopy operations. Hwoever I don't see any files being copied - and no hello world in my activity log.

**How can I make sure the file is even being executed? Apparently it is not... how do I fix that?**

Diagnostics log:

```
<BuildInformationNode Id="1f5d1357-a2c5-47d9-b139-70fef8b3bf9a" ParentId="d57481f2-40eb-4cfa-80b6-8f3d81628f0c" Type="ActivityTracking">
  <Fields>
    <InformationField Name="ActivityInstanceId" Value="7732" />
    <InformationField Name="ActivityType" Value="RunScript" />
    <InformationField Name="DisplayName" Value="Run optional script before MSBuild" />
    <InformationField Name="Duration" Value="00:00:00" />
    <InformationField Name="State" Value="Closed" />
    <InformationField Name="StartTime" Value="2015-05-11T09:07:18.9934208Z" />
    <InformationField Name="FinishTime" Value="2015-05-11T09:07:18.9934208Z" />
  </Fields>
  <Children>
    <BuildInformationNode Id="2415a1b2-be01-4345-aa83-a32d21ba3de8" ParentId="1f5d1357-a2c5-47d9-b139-70fef8b3bf9a" Type="ActivityInput">
      <Fields>
        <InformationField Name="EnvironmentVariables" />
        <InformationField Name="Enabled" Value="True" />
        <InformationField Name="Arguments" Value="$/TP4/Company/Area/Solution/Business/.scripts/prebuild.ps1" />
        <InformationField Name="FilePath" />
      </Fields>
      <Children />
    </BuildInformationNode>
    <BuildInformationNode Id="db012d8c-6206-4037-b2ad-b01ccdbe6d43" ParentId="1f5d1357-a2c5-47d9-b139-70fef8b3bf9a" Type="ActivityOutput">
      <Fields>
        <InformationField Name="Result" Value="0" />
      </Fields>
      <Children />
    </BuildInformationNode>
  </Children>
</BuildInformationNode>
```

To be on the safe side (for testing purposes) I set the Powershell Execution Policy to Unrestricted.

Answer (score 0):

...I put the script into the script **arguments** configuration setting instead of the script **path**. :-(